# Missing Libraries on Linux with Rust and Amethyst

Tags: linux, rust, ld, rust-cargo, amethyst

When I try to `cargo build` the 'hello world' of [amethyst](https://www.amethyst.rs/) on Ubuntu 18.04, I get an error about missing libraries from lxbcb.  I'm not sure what this error is trying to tell me or how to fix it.  It seems like I'm missing libraries `-lxcb-render`, `-lxcb-shap`, and `-lxcb-xfixes`, but I can't seem to find them.

The hello world code of amethyst

```
extern crate amethyst;

use amethyst::{
    prelude::*,
    renderer::{DisplayConfig, DrawFlat, Pipeline, PosNormTex, RenderBundle, Stage, VirtualKeyCode},
    utils::application_root_dir,
    input::is_key_down,
};

struct Example;

impl SimpleState for Example {}

fn main() -> amethyst::Result<()> {
    amethyst::start_logger(Default::default());

    let path = format!(
        "{}/resources/display_config.ron",
        application_root_dir()
    );
    let config = DisplayConfig::load(&path);

    let pipe = Pipeline::build().with_stage(
        Stage::with_backbuffer()
            .clear_target([0.00196, 0.23726, 0.21765, 1.0], 1.0)
            .with_pass(DrawFlat::<PosNormTex>::new()),
    );

    let game_data =
        GameDataBuilder::default().with_bundle(RenderBundle::new(pipe, Some(config)))?;
    let mut game = Application::new("./", Example, game_data)?;

    game.run();

    Ok(())
}
```

`cargo build` output (some of the `rustc` command removed since there is a character limit)

```
brad@rhyme:~/Development/amethyst_setup/gametest$ cargo run --verbose
       Fresh unicode-xid v0.1.0
       Fresh cc v1.0.35
       Fresh semver-parser v0.7.0
       Fresh cfg-if v0.1.7
       Fresh nodrop v0.1.13
       Fresh rand_core v0.4.0
       Fresh autocfg v0.1.2
       Fresh xml-rs v0.8.0
       Fresh scopeguard v0.3.3
       Fresh memoffset v0.2.1
       Fresh lazy_static v1.3.0
       Fresh stable_deref_trait v1.1.1
       Fresh void v1.0.2
       Fresh bitflags v1.0.4
       Fresh crossbeam-utils v0.5.0
       Fresh pkg-config v0.3.14
       Fresh same-file v1.0.4
       Fresh linked-hash-map v0.5.2
       Fresh downcast-rs v1.0.4
       Fresh either v1.5.2
       Fresh atom v0.3.5
       Fresh mopa v0.2.2
       Fresh xdg v2.2.0
       Fresh rawpointer v0.1.0
       Fresh rustc-demangle v0.1.14
       Fresh futures v0.1.26
       Fresh fnv v1.0.6
       Fresh tuple_utils v0.2.0
       Fresh libm v0.1.2
       Fresh mint v0.5.1
       Fresh adler32 v1.0.3
       Fresh unicode-xid v0.0.4
       Fresh percent-encoding v1.0.1
       Fresh lzw v0.10.0
       Fresh approx v0.1.1
       Fresh color_quant v1.0.1
       Fresh quote v0.3.15
       Fresh build_const v0.2.1
       Fresh scoped_threadpool v0.1.9
       Fresh siphasher v0.2.3
       Fresh xi-unicode v0.1.0
       Fresh wavefront_obj v5.1.0
       Fresh hetseq v0.2.0
       Fresh ansi_term v0.11.0
       Fresh unicode-width v0.1.5
       Fresh claxon v0.3.2
       Fresh hound v3.4.0
       Fresh matches v0.1.8
       Fresh strsim v0.8.0
       Fresh vec_map v0.8.1
       Fresh hashbrown v0.2.2
       Fresh float-ord v0.2.0
       Fresh fluent-locale v0.4.1
       Fresh unicode-segmentation v1.2.1
       Fresh semver v0.9.0
       Fresh crossbeam-utils v0.2.2
       Fresh proc-macro2 v0.3.8
       Fresh cmake v0.1.38
       Fresh rand_core v0.3.1
       Fresh crossbeam-utils v0.6.5
       Fresh rand_jitter v0.1.3
       Fresh colored v1.7.0
       Fresh owning_ref v0.4.0
       Fresh owning_ref v0.3.3
       Fresh xml-rs v0.7.0
       Fresh walkdir v2.2.7
       Fresh itertools v0.7.11
       Fresh synom v0.11.3
       Fresh inflate v0.4.5
       Fresh gif v0.10.1
       Fresh phf_shared v0.7.24
       Fresh annotate-snippets v0.1.0
       Fresh textwrap v0.11.0
       Fresh proc-macro2 v0.4.27
       Fresh rustc_version v0.2.3
       Fresh libc v0.2.51
       Fresh arrayvec v0.4.10
       Fresh rand_hc v0.1.0
       Fresh rand_xorshift v0.1.1
       Fresh rand_isaac v0.1.1
       Fresh quote v0.5.2
       Fresh num-traits v0.2.6
       Fresh byteorder v1.3.1
       Fresh lock_api v0.1.5
       Fresh khronos_api v2.2.0
       Fresh khronos_api v3.1.0
       Fresh typenum v1.10.0
       Fresh nonzero_signed v1.0.3
       Fresh matrixmultiply v0.1.15
       Fresh syn v0.11.11
       Fresh quote v0.6.12
       Fresh libloading v0.5.0
       Fresh crossbeam-epoch v0.3.1
       Fresh rand v0.5.6
       Fresh rand v0.4.6
       Fresh num_cpus v1.10.0
       Fresh nix v0.13.0
       Fresh crossbeam-epoch v0.7.1
       Fresh rand_os v0.1.3
       Fresh crossbeam-epoch v0.5.2
       Fresh crossbeam-epoch v0.6.1
       Fresh memmap v0.7.0
       Fresh shared_library v0.1.9
       Fresh time v0.1.42
       Fresh slice-deque v0.1.16
       Fresh phf v0.7.24
       Fresh atty v0.2.11
       Fresh memmap v0.6.2
       Fresh fluent-syntax v0.1.1
       Fresh dirs v1.0.5
       Fresh ordered-float v1.0.2
       Fresh approx v0.3.2
       Fresh line_drawing v0.7.0
       Fresh backtrace-sys v0.1.28
       Fresh num-integer v0.1.39
       Fresh syn v0.13.11
       Fresh num-traits v0.1.43
       Fresh minimp3-sys v0.3.1
       Fresh rand_chacha v0.1.1
       Fresh rustc-hash v1.0.1
       Fresh stb_truetype v0.2.6
       Fresh rand_pcg v0.1.2
       Fresh fxhash v0.2.1
       Fresh deflate v0.7.19
       Fresh base64 v0.10.1
       Fresh ogg v0.7.0
       Fresh syn v0.15.32
       Fresh wayland-scanner v0.21.12
       Fresh generic-array v0.11.1
       Fresh x11-dl v2.18.3
       Fresh gfx_macros v0.2.1
       Fresh alsa-sys v0.1.2
       Fresh crc v1.8.1
       Fresh dlib v0.4.1
       Fresh crossbeam-deque v0.2.0
       Fresh crossbeam-deque v0.7.1
       Fresh rand v0.3.23
       Fresh crossbeam-deque v0.5.2
       Fresh osmesa-sys v0.1.2
       Fresh intl_pluralrules v1.0.3
       Fresh clap v2.33.0
       Fresh backtrace v0.3.15
       Fresh num-bigint v0.2.2
       Fresh num-iter v0.1.37
       Fresh chrono v0.4.6
       Fresh cgmath v0.16.1
       Fresh glsl-layout-derive v0.1.1
       Fresh servo-freetype-sys v4.0.5
       Fresh expat-sys v2.1.6
       Fresh minimp3 v0.3.2
       Fresh rand v0.6.5
       Fresh serde_derive v1.0.90
       Fresh derivative v1.0.2
       Fresh shred-derive v0.5.1
       Fresh num-derive v0.2.4
       Fresh euclid_macros v0.1.0
       Fresh synstructure v0.10.1
       Fresh amethyst_derive v0.3.0
       Fresh getset v0.0.7
       Fresh wayland-sys v0.21.12
       Fresh rayon-core v1.4.1
       Fresh rusttype v0.7.6
       Fresh cpal v0.8.2
       Fresh cgmath v0.14.1
       Fresh error-chain v0.12.0
       Fresh num-rational v0.2.1
       Fresh png v0.12.0
       Fresh rustc_version_runtime v0.1.5
       Fresh serde v1.0.90
       Fresh genmesh v0.6.2
       Fresh servo-fontconfig-sys v4.0.7
       Fresh twox-hash v1.2.0
       Fresh freetype v0.4.1
       Fresh tiff v0.2.2
       Fresh euclid v0.19.8
       Fresh failure_derive v0.1.5
       Fresh wayland-commons v0.21.12
       Fresh rayon v1.0.3
       Fresh andrew v0.2.1
       Fresh glyph_brush_layout v0.1.5
       Fresh vergen v2.1.3
       Fresh smallvec v0.6.9
       Fresh log v0.4.6
       Fresh num-complex v0.2.1
       Fresh draw_state v0.8.0
       Fresh ron v0.4.2
       Fresh bincode v1.1.3
       Fresh uuid v0.7.4
       Fresh lyon_geom v0.12.4
       Fresh servo-fontconfig v0.4.0
       Fresh failure v0.1.5
       Fresh parking_lot_core v0.3.1
       Fresh parking_lot_core v0.2.14
       Fresh wayland-client v0.21.12
       Fresh gl_generator v0.9.0
       Fresh parking_lot_core v0.4.0
       Fresh hibitset v0.5.4
       Fresh shred v0.7.2
       Fresh gl_generator v0.10.0
       Fresh alga v0.7.2
       Fresh jpeg-decoder v0.1.15
       Fresh xcb v0.8.2
       Fresh lewton v0.9.4
       Fresh num v0.2.0
       Fresh glyph_brush v0.4.2
       Fresh unicode-normalization v0.1.8
       Fresh crossbeam-channel v0.3.8
       Fresh fern v0.5.8
       Fresh gfx_core v0.8.3
       Fresh parking_lot v0.6.4
       Fresh parking_lot v0.5.5
       Fresh amethyst_config v0.9.0
       Fresh lyon_path v0.12.0
       Fresh laminar v0.1.0
       Fresh fluent v0.4.3
       Fresh wayland-protocols v0.21.12
       Fresh parking_lot v0.7.1
       Fresh nalgebra v0.16.13
       Fresh image v0.20.1
       Fresh x11-clipboard v0.3.1
       Fresh rodio v0.8.1
       Fresh crossbeam-channel v0.2.6
       Fresh glsl-layout v0.1.1
       Fresh gfx v0.17.1
       Fresh minterpolate v0.4.0
       Fresh shrev v1.0.1
       Fresh smithay-client-toolkit v0.4.5
       Fresh font-kit v0.1.0
       Fresh crossbeam v0.4.1
       Fresh clipboard v0.5.0
       Fresh gfx_glyph v0.13.3
       Fresh specs v0.14.3
       Fresh winit v0.18.1
       Fresh gfx_gl v0.5.0
       Fresh specs-hierarchy v0.3.0
       Fresh glutin v0.19.0
       Fresh amethyst_core v0.5.0
       Fresh gfx_device_gl v0.15.5
       Fresh amethyst_assets v0.6.0
       Fresh gfx_window_glutin v0.27.0
       Fresh amethyst_network v0.3.0
       Fresh amethyst_renderer v0.10.4
       Fresh amethyst_audio v0.5.0
       Fresh amethyst_locale v0.4.0
       Fresh amethyst_input v0.6.0
       Fresh amethyst_animation v0.5.0
       Fresh amethyst_controls v0.4.0
       Fresh amethyst_ui v0.5.0
       Fresh amethyst_utils v0.5.0
       Fresh amethyst v0.10.0
   Compiling gametest v0.1.0 (/home/brad/Development/amethyst_setup/gametest)
     Running `rustc --edition=2018 --crate-name gametest src/main.rs --color always --crate-type bin --emit=dep-info,link -C debuginfo=2 -C metadata=8a344c992f010775 -C extra-filename=-8a344c992f010775 --out-dir /home/brad/Development/amethyst_setup/gametest/target/debug/deps -C incremental=/home/brad/Development/amethyst_setup/gametest/target/debug/incremental -L dependency=/home/brad/Development/amethyst_setup/gametest/target/debug/deps --extern amethyst=/home/brad/Development/amethyst_setup/gametest/target/debug/deps/libamethyst-618119f166e173bf.rlib -L native=/home/brad/Development/amethyst_setup/gametest/target/debug/build/backtrace-sys-af21dccdd6a6a2ad/out -L native=/home/brad/Development/amethyst_setup/gametest/target/debug/build/libloading-ec1dd9ac5a65377a/out ...-Wl,--end-group" "/home/brad/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcompiler_builtins-c4b4b16c70e666d9.rlib" "-Wl,-Bdynamic" "-lexpat" "-lxcb" "-lxcb" "-lxcb" "-lxcb" "-lxcb-render" "-lxcb-shape" "-lxcb-xfixes" "-lasound" "-ldl" "-ldl" "-lutil" "-lutil" "-ldl" "-lrt" "-lpthread" "-lgcc_s" "-lc" "-lm" "-lrt" "-lpthread" "-lutil" "-lutil"
  = note: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lxcb-render
          /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lxcb-shape
          /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lxcb-xfixes
          collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status


error: aborting due to previous error

error: Could not compile `gametest`.

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `rustc --edition=2018 --crate-name gametest src/main.rs --color always --crate-type bin --emit=dep-info,link -C debuginfo=2 -C metadata=8a344c992f010775 -C extra-filename=-8a344c992f010775 --out-dir /home/brad/Development/amethyst_setup/gametest/target/debug/deps -C incremental=/home/brad/Development/amethyst_setup/gametest/target/debug/incremental -L dependency=/home/brad/Development/amethyst_setup/gametest/target/debug/deps --extern amethyst=/home/brad/Development/amethyst_setup/gametest/target/debug/deps/libamethyst-618119f166e173bf.rlib -L native=/home/brad/Development/amethyst_setup/gametest/target/debug/build/backtrace-sys-af21dccdd6a6a2ad/out -L native=/home/brad/Development/amethyst_setup/gametest/target/debug/build/libloading-ec1dd9ac5a65377a/out -L native=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L native=/home/brad/Development/amethyst_setup/gametest/target/debug/build/minimp3-sys-23d2f40602e9e7e8/out -L native=/home/brad/Development/amethyst_setup/gametest/target/debug/build/servo-freetype-sys-3c5b6f9e4acfbf1c/out/lib -L native=/home/brad/Development/amethyst_setup/gametest/target/debug/build/servo-fontconfig-sys-e66049aa5a9b8f2a/out -L native=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` (exit code: 1)
```

Package Info (I think this is the package that would contain what I'm missing)

```
brad@rhyme:~/Development/amethyst_setup/gametest$ sudo apt-get install libx11-xcb-dev
[sudo] password for brad: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libx11-xcb-dev is already the newest version (2:1.6.4-3ubuntu0.2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 25 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Depending of your distro, just install the "libxcb" package

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.  I think that package would be `libx11-scb-dev`, which I have already installed.  How can I find out what package these libraries(?) belong to?  I'll edit to include this package output now.  Thanks :)

Comment: Not saying that SO is not the right place, but you may have more answers asking in the Amethyst discord

Comment: You can search for the library names. https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/libxcb-shape0-dev/filelist https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/libxcb-render0-dev/filelist

Comment: It's possible that `apt-cache search` can be used to find those libraries, but I'm not near an Ubuntu system to verify.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like I missed installing some dependencies.

`sudo apt install pkg-config libasound2-dev libssl-dev cmake libfreetype6-dev libexpat1-dev libxcb-composite0-dev`

https://github.com/amethyst/amethyst#debianubuntu

Comment: I also needed `libx11-dev`